# Where does EE2 get the latest member_id from?

Tags: ee2, members, database, member-details

I've deleted a bunch of members (on purpose), so that I only have member_id '1' left. Now if I create a new member... The newest member_id is '176' and then increments as I add more… If the members have been deleted where did expression engine get that number from? The last member_id created must be stored somewhere in order for EE to reference it? I can’t find it for the life of me.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with ExpressionEngine. This is a counter that exists in MySQL when a column is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT` and is the primary key.

You can reset the column in this table if you'd like.

**TAKE A BACKUP OF YOUR `exp_members` TABLE BEFORE PROCEEDING**

This warning is just in case you fall down the rabbit hole of miss-typed syntax.

Run this MySQL query (provided your table prefix is the standard `exp`) to reset your counter to whatever you'd like:

```
USE `my_database_name`;
ALTER TABLE `exp_members` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Set `1` to whatever you want the counter to start with (it will default to highest current index plus one if you have a row with 1 for the primary key). Remember, messing with your production database requires serious caution.

Comment: Thank you @jrohafer, how is the auto_increment number remembered? Is it just in memory? Also, how can I contact you for a project?

Comment: It just lives as meta-data in your MySQL information schema, I believe. Either way, it's an implementation of a counter in standard table engines like MyISAM and InnoDB. Unfortunately, I couldn't be more loaded with work right now, so I'm not available to take on any contracts/jobs, Sorry!